# How do I use basic authentication on AWS OpenSearch with SAML enabled

Tags: aws-lambda, saml, basic-authentication, opensearch

I have a new OpenSearch instance with SAML enabled. I also have the internal user database and basic auth enabled.

My users can log in with SAML as expected - all good. But how do my lambdas authenticate? I was expecting to use username and password as follows:

`https://user:password@domain`

but this redirects to my SAML IdP as if I hadn't provided a password. What am I missing?

I've checked that both saml_auth_domain and basic_internal_auth_domain authentication methods are enabled.

Answer (score 0):

In the Opensearch role you created (with correct permissions inside of Opensearch) you map a backend role as you do with the SAML backend roles but instead you use the ARN for the Lambda, the same goes for ECS etc.

```
arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxx:role/YourLambdaExecutionRole
```